# Problemas con la codificacion UTF-8 en mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, utf-8

Tengo problemas con la codificación de caracteres con las ñ y tildes, la pagina esta en utf-8 y la tabla y la DB en utf-8_general_ci pero sucede como en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna solución?

$conexion = new mysqli($host,$usuariodb,$clavedb,$basededatos);

Comment: Por favor revisa la respuesta a esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%C3%A1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un posible ejemplo:

```
//Tu conexión
$conexion = new mysqli($host,$usuariodb,$clavedb,$basededatos);

//Comprobamos conexión.
if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("La conexión fallo: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

//Caracteres UTF-8.
if (!$conexion->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", $conexion->error);
    exit();
}

//Añades tu sentencia.
```

[Manual mysqli::set_charset](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Answer (score 0):

Después de crear la conexión y antes de hacer el insert:

```
$conexion->set_charset('utf8');
```